# Incremental element value in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, position, increment

I have an xsd schema for xml validation. This schema defines an element:

```
<xsd:element name="num" default="0">
  <xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:union memberTypes="xsd:integer xsd:positiveInteger" />
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

There's also a unique constraint for `num` element values.

What I want is require the element values to be in ascending order. How do I do this? Maybe a loop or a position check, or maybe it is possible to assign some incremental value to the element?

Sample data:

```
<num>0</num> 
<num>1</num> 
<num>2</num>
<num>3</num>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to specify such a constraint using XSD schema. You could specify such a constraint using the Schematron schema language.

e.g.

```
<sch:rule context="num[preceding-sibling::num]">
  <sch:let name="the-preceding-value" value="preceding-sibling::num[1]"/>
  <sch:let name="the-value" value="."/>
  <sch:assert test="number($the-value) = (number($the-preceding-value)+1)">The value
      <sch:value-of select="$the-value"/> is not in sequence; it must be <sch:value-of
    select="$the-preceding-value + 1"/></sch:assert>
</sch:rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In XSD 1.1 (implemented currently in Xerces and Saxon) you can have an assertion on the parent type of the num elements:

```
<xs:assert test="every $i in 1 to count(num) satisfies num[$i] = $i - 1"/>
```

(Note that it can't be an assertion on the num element itself, because the validity of an element isn't allowed to depend on any elements outside its own content.)